# Change the native confirm/alert

Tags: javascript

I would like delete the title of my popup JavaScrip but i don't know how i can and where i make the code.

This is my code :

```
<a href="javascript:;"
 onclick="if(confirm('voulez-vous vraiment supprimer cette 
station?')) 
window.location.href='Supprimer_Station.php?id_sta=<?php echo 
$valeur['ssiphone_idstation']; ?>&act=supprimer'; ">
```

Tthanks for your help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't control the appearance of `confirm()` or `alert()` Javascript popups, because they are native controls, so their appearance is based on the OS and the browser.

What you can do:

- create your [own Javascript dialog](http://www.google.hu/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=how%20to%20create%20javascript%20modal%20dialog)
- use a pre-written dialog like [jQuery UI's dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal)
- if you don't want to include a full library (like jQuery UI) for a simple dialog, try something like [javascript-simple-dialog](http://code.google.com/p/javascript-simple-dialog/)

Answer (score 4):

You mean alert? You can't control/remove the title from javascript alert.

Answer (score 0):

You can't because `confirm` is a javascript function which you can't change. Might want to consider using other solution like a modal window where you can add custom header/title and stuff.