# Javascript alert boxes design

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change the native confirm/alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803305/change-the-native-confirm-alert)

I would like to know if you can change the style of an alert box (i.e color, font). Can someone give me an example?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change this. You can create your own, using absolutely-positioned HTML elements. These are called [Modal Dialogs or Modal Windows](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/05/27/modal-windows-in-modern-web-design/).

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

Instead, you can create a fake dialog in Javascript, like [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Answer (score 1):

No, I'm afraid that is not possible.

With JavaScript, you are limited to only 3 popup boxes: alert, prompt and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried jQuery's UI? They have a dialog box you can customize.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of the jQuery UI dialog, which may be what you're looking after:

http://jsfiddle.net/2f3LG/

As mentioned before, different "themes" (css styles) are available to choose or customize yourself here: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/