# How to change OK/Cancel button's text in browsers to desired text?

Tags: php, javascript, user-interface

Is there a way to change confirmation's button text to desired text? (YES/NO or OK/CANCEL)
My language is not English and this issue has really spoiled the site UI?

**EDIT**
I'm using JavaScript in my PHP web app to show confirmation dialog boxes.

Comment: You don't give us any hint regarding the technology you're using.  One possible solution is to create your own dialogs with the buttons labeled as you wish.

Comment: There is no 'JAVA Script' though we can assume you meant 'JavaScript'. Alas, that still doesn't quite answer the question. I'll update my answer below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the native confirm/alert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803305/change-the-native-confirm-alert)

Answer (score 1):

You can't (for hopefully obvious security reasons).

As for native language, that'd be up to the device OS to support and browser to recognize.

As Jay points out, you could create your own dialogs.

With JavaScript, there are two main ways to handle this.

One:

```
confirm("Do you like eggs?");
```

This produces a native confirmation dialog (with affirmative and negative buttons) that the user has to click. If they click in the affirmative, the script continues. If the negative, it ends.

This is the easiest to implement as it leverages native functionality of the browser. It's also what will be natively localized provided the OS and browser support that and the user has set it up.

Two:

The second option is to create your own modal. This is typically done by using JavaScript to update the DOM to mask out the background (usually with a large DIV) and then create a 'pop-up' that would be a DIV styled via CSS. You can then create any interactions you'd like with any wording you'd like. Most of the standards UI JS libraries (such as jQueryUI) now have these as built in components.