# Change the position of default File Selector dialog box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, winapi, dialog

I am making an ecommerce store where we need to show a "Choose File" dialog box in order to select the require file and upload the same.

**Scenario in Windows:**
When the Select File dialog box opens, it is positioned on the top-left corner. I need to move it just above and at center of the popup window on which the Choose File button is placed.

[image]

I have read a lot of articles that suggest to use Windows api for this, but the web application can be accessed on any operating system, so making this operating system specific will not be an appropriate solution.

Please suggest any way we can do this. Need something like the attached screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5803511/12411571

This answer assume you are building Web Site. Web Site are displayed on browser. Broswer are just show your pages and helps to use device-native features. We have to know "helps to use", not "fully connect to use". We can't customize device-native features like connecting native file systems, select form UI and confirm dialog, etc....

So, you can't customize dialog position. Because browser doesn't provide API.